# can I use Bootstrap components without using the entire framework

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I would like to make use of the components without using the responsive content and grid controls. Would this require a complete install or partial install of bootstrap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize twitter bootstrap to use only what you need:  http://getbootstrap.com/customize/